# Sonarqube Quality Gate Hide Coverage

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, bamboo

When I apply some dashboard to a specific quality gate, my coverage section is not shown anymore.
I tried to remove the quality gate from my dashboard and then the coverage appears on the dashboard.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Quality Gates to projects.
In Sonar go to Quality Gates tab --> Then to Projects --> All projects
Select the projects you want to enable Quality Gates. Then in With Projects will show the project names.
Now the dashboard of all these projects will show Quality Gates after each build.